# Power Spectral Density of a Filter

Tags: power-spectral-density, z-transform, digital-filters, feedback

I need to calculate the output power spectral density of the following digital filter

[image]

My calculations are as follows:

$y\left(n\right)\:=\:x\left(n-1\right)+d\left[x\left(n-1\right)+x\left(n\right)\right]$

$Y\left(z\right)\:=\:X\left(z\right)z^{-1}+d\left[X\left(z\right)z^{-1}+X\left(z\right)\right]$

$Y\left(z\right)\:=\:X\left(z\right)\left[\left(1+d\right)z^{-1}+d\right]$

$\frac{Y\left(z\right)}{X\left(z\right)}=\:H\left(z\right)=\left(1+d\right)z^{-1}+d$

Did I get this equation right? would somebody help me please because this diagram is kind of confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A digital filter doesn't have power spectral density, a signal has. I guess what you want is the transfer function of this filter, i.e., $H(z)=Y(z)/X(z)$.

Let's add two intermediate signal $u(n)$ and $v(n)$ in the diagram.

[image]

We have:

$$
y(n) = v(n-1) + du(n) \tag{1}
$$
$$
u(n)=v(n-1)+x(n)\tag{2}
$$
$$
v(n) = x(n) -du(n) \tag{3}
$$

Take Z-transform and we get
$$
Y(z) = V(z)z^{-1} + dU(z) \tag{4}
$$
$$
U(z) = V(z)z^{-1}+X(z)\tag{5}
$$
$$
V(z)=X(z)-dU(z)\tag{6}
$$

Furthermore, we can derive that

$$
V(z)=X(z)-d\Big[V(z)z^{-1} + X(z)\Big]
$$

$$
\frac{V(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{1-d}{1+dz^{-1}}
$$

$$
Y(z)=V(z)z^{-1} + d\Big[V(z)z^{-1}+X(z) \Big] =(1+d)V(z)z^{-1} + dX(z)
$$

Thus,
$$
H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = (1+d) \frac{V(z)}{X(z)} z^{-1} + d = (1+d) \frac{(1-d)z^{-1}}{1+dz^{-1}} +d
$$

Comment: very impressive. Thank you very much. This for some reason was very confusing. I see how to solve something like that from now on. Basically to introduce new signals.

Comment: So if the signal, has an input power spectral density say $\sigma _x^2$ how would someone find the output power spectral density? I would appreciate it if you provide this update to the answer.

Comment: Power spectral density of input signal is $P_{xx} = X(e^{j\omega}) X^*(e^{j\omega})$. Since you already have the transfer function $H(z)$ and also the frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$, just take $Y(e^{j\omega}) = H(e^{j\omega}) X(e^{j\omega})$ into account and you will see the answer.